# Push notifications (iPhone) give "111 Connection refused"

Tags: php, iphone, ssl, push

When  I try to send Push Notifications I get this error: "Connection refused", but I don't know why... I've uploaded my apns-dev.pem in the same directory as well in the root-directory but that won't work either.

```
<?php
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is the alert text', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($payload);
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';
$apnsPass = 'secret';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $apnsPass);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if (!$apns) {
    echo "Error: $errorString ($error)";
}

// Do this for each
$deviceToken = '00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000';
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
// End do

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
?>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? When I remove the passphrase and don't send it it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a passphrase unless your .pem file requires one.  The connection requires peer verification (option verify_peer) turned on. Also, make sure $apnsCert is the valid path to the certificate, you can use an absolute path as a sanity check.

Lastly, this shouldn't effect your ability to connect, but your device token needs to be valid.

Comment: Really thanks, I'm going to check if this works.
Do you mean the ftp-path (/public-html/directory/file.pem) or (http://www.server.com/directory/file.pem) by absolute path?

I get this error before I send any data, so it's not the device-token, I think...

Thanks :D!

Comment: It doesn't work :(..., below is my answer to prevent that error.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the outgoing port 2195 is open.This would be in your firewall config.

Comment: Yep, that actually was the problem. Thanks for helping though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've know fixed that error by adding this: STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT

Know I'm not getting any errors, but I don't receive any notification. I think the Dev-token is not valid know, so, this is how it look like

numbers numbers numbers numbers numbers numbers numbers numbers.

The spaces are removed in this line:
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

**Edit: I founded the problem:**
My server is refusing the outgoing port, just sent a mail, hoping they can activate it...