# iPhone: Connection refused error while connection Apple's Push Notification Service

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been scratching my head since long now to get rid of following error message.

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)

I have tried multiple times generating the correct certificate and made sure that project is signed with the correct bundle identifier.

I have also tried using testing script PHP(https://devforums.apple.com/message/50461) and Python (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code) but both are giving same error message.

Could anyone please help me to know how to get rid of this error message?

Thanks.

Comment: I am gonna to check if my machine is refusing the 2195 port - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444753/push-notifications-iphone-give-111-connection-refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha...Our firewall setup to not allow any other ports not listed in settings. Asked admin people to add it and it doesn't show this error message now....!! I have sent and message but didn't receive since last 5 minutes. I know that APNS messages are not guaranteed. Will wait for some more time. Hopefully it arrives.. :)