# Not Getting Push Notification for Production Certificate

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have read many answers on this topic but issue not resolved by suggested solutions. My issue is that I am not getting Push Notifications for Production Certificate. Same Push Notifications are successfully getting in Development certificate. I specially want to say that my device tokens for production and development environment is entirely different. So there is no issue for same device token. Also, i am using different profiles for both. Means to say, there is not configuration issue on app level.

We are using PHP as a server that is sending push notifications.

Here are my two questions:

1. Is there any thing missing at server side? For which PHP server is sending Push Notifications for development environment successfully and for Production environment, its generating problem?
2. Am i missing any thing in the app?

I will be very thankful to all of you. I am stuck on this issue. Many Thanks in advance

Comment: In the PHP server, do you get any error from the APNs server when sending the notifications?

Comment: is your app live in the app store?

Comment: @Natarajan App is live on App Store without Push Notification related stuff; As it will come in Next Release

Comment: What url are u using in your PHP service?

Comment: Have you check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447025/how-to-test-production-push-notifications

Comment: check my completed answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055756/how-can-i-generate-pem-file-for-push-notifications-in-iphone for push notification certifcates

Comment: @AhmedZ. URL: gateway.push.apple.com AND Port: 2195

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya Doing the same

Comment: @msmq server side you can change url and password for production mode ? URL : gateway.push.apple.com

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya using same URL at server side gateway.push.apple.com
And there is no any password for production and development at all.

Answer (score 0):

check php function for iphone push notification...

```
function iphone_notification($deviceToken,$message,$not_type,$sound,$vibration_type){
            $passphrase = '******';
            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
            $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
            $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'sound' => $sound);
            $body['notification_type'] = $not_type;
            $body['vibration_type'] = $vibration_type;
            //1 = news;
            //99 = other;
            //echo $err."<br>".$errstr;
            $payload = json_encode($body);
            $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
            fclose($fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem. If your .pem file is correct then using following setting you will get push notification. ([check terminal commands to make .pem](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1))

```
//for development profile
$apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';

//for production you should use this
$apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';s.
```

for more detail check this [link1 >>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html) [link2 >>](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/ios-push-notifications-in-php/)