# Push notification Error 111 connection refused

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am trying to integrate pushnotification with my app. and since one week i am getting same error '111 connection refused'. I checked every thing. generated .pem file 3 times to confirm that there is no any issue with .pem  file. Certificate path is correct. Port number is 2195.  Please, help me what would be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: have you check your payload size. It may be problem your payload size. Because apple only allowed 256 byte of for sending push notification.

Comment: Plese checkout
[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444753/push-notifications-iphone-give-111-connection-refused) .It may be help you.

Comment: @RahulPatel Yes we tested with passing 'Hello' only. It's not working with that also same error.

Comment: Have you check above question link?

Comment: @RahulPatel Thanks, Yes, I think my server port 2195 is not open.

Answer (score 0):

please check this 2 links

1.[Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)

2.[Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial: Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2)

may be you will get some better ideas from here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know these links. I already integrated push notification in other project. But this time i am getting error 111.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a server error . Usually large sites will have front end servers that build and serve the dynamic content to your App with backend databases and information caches that retrieve the information to be built into a page. The error code tells that the webserver is not connecting to the backend for some reason. not real sure it has anything to do with you.

Just a guess this error may be caused by excessive traffic on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the right server? For the production certificate it should be 
gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net

so not gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net as for the development certificate.